# WPF MVVM control won't update when its bound VM Property changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm writing an MVVM application using Prism Framework. I can't make my label update when the property value changes. When I create the model and assign initial value to the Property, the lable bound to it gets updated. But then when I change the Property during application lifetime, the label won't update its content.

Here is my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="700">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <Button x:Name="btnStart" Command="{Binding Path=Start}" Content="StartProcess"/>

            <GroupBox Header="Current Operation">
                <Label x:Name="lblCurrentOperation" Content="{ Binding  CurrentOperationLabel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </GroupBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class MyModelViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private MyModel model;
    private string currentOpeartion;

    public DelegateCommand Start { get; private set; }

    public string CurrentOperationLabel
    {
        get { return currentOpeartion; }
        set { SetProperty(ref currentOpeartion, value); }
    }

    public MyModelViewModel ()
    {
        model = new MyModel ();

        Start  = new DelegateCommand (model.Start);
        CurrentOperationLabel = model.CurrentOperation; //Bind model to the ViewModel
    }   
}
```

And in my Model, I change the label when the "Start" command is invoked.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string CurrentOperation { get; set; }

    public MyModel()
    {
        CurrentOperation = "aaa"; //This will make the label show "aaa"
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        CurrentOperation = "new label"; //This should alter the Label in the view, but it doesn't
    }
}
```

Comment: the code you are showing doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged i assume that this is in the not provided BindableBase can you add that code?

Comment: try to set breakpoint at setter of `CurrentOperationLabel` when you've called `Start()` method of your model class and see whether the new value 'new label' comes.

Comment: My initial suspicion is that your start method is changing the model not the viewModel so the View model doesn't know its changed so can't notify

Comment: Where you've commented *'Bind model to the ViewModel'*, that's not what you're doing.  You're just copying the current value to the view model and it's never updated.

Comment: @MikeT `BindableBase` does implement INPC and `SetProperty` will cause the event to be raised if the value is different.

Comment: @CharlesMager thanks i didn't make the connection to `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that in `Start` method you modifies a property of a model (i.e. `CurrentOperation`)  and not a property of a view model (i.e. `CurrentOperationLabel`). XAML knows nothing about model because it is bound to a view model. In other words when you modify `MyModel.CurrentOperation` property XAML is not notified about this fact.

To fix this problem you should change the structure of your code. You need to refresh a view model after updating a model. My suggestion is to modify `MyModelViewModel` in this way:

```
public class MyModelViewModel : BindableBase
{
      //...

      public void InnerStart()
      {
          model.Start();
          //Refresh the view model from the model
      }

      public MyModelViewModel ()
      {
        model = new MyModel ();

        Start  = InnerStart;
        CurrentOperationLabel = model.CurrentOperation; 
    }   
}
```

The idea is that button's clicks should be handled in the view model which is responsible for the communication with the model. Additionally it updates properties accordingly based on the current state of the model.

Comment: Yes, you've got a point. How should I then notify the ViewModel, that Model's property changed? I wouldn't mind if you fixed my code :)